# Points of drillhole data to 3D lines in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

In GRASS 7.0 I have a 3D vector file which are several SPT drill holes, with the NSPT values at each interval.
I was able to export these points to Paraview through "v.out.vtk -cn input = nspt_3D type = point layer = 1 output = nspt_3D2.vtk" and visualize them in 3D, each point with its NSPT value.
How could I do to export in GRASS 7 these points as lines and use the filter tubes in Paraview?